# How to send data to json webservice?

Tags: php, json, webservice-client

How can do this curl command with PHP?

```
curl -i -X GET -u user:userpass --url http://test/statistics.json \
-d '{"period":{"startdate":"YYYY-MM-DD+hh:mm:ss","enddate":"YYYY-MM-DD+hh:mm:ss"}}' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-type: application/json'
```

I have tried with this.

```
$oar = '{"period":{"startdate":"2018-07-06+00:00:00","enddate":"2018-07-07+00:00:00"}}';
$ch = curl_init();

$service_url = $myURL;
//$content= json_decode("{'period':{'startdate':'2018-06-02+00:00:00','enddate':'2018-06-03+00:00:'0'}}");
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "fsd:fsdfsdfsdfdf");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_GET, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $oar);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($curl_response);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($response);
echo $response;
```

But get a response from the server only GET is accepted.
Works if I exclude `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $oar);`. But then the service ignore the date range and sets a default range.

-- update

This works fine! Thanks to **Ray A**!

```
$service_url = "https://test/urk.json";
$data = array("period" => array("startdate"=>"2018-06-01+00:00:00","enddate"=>"2018-07-07+00:00:00"));
$data_string = json_encode($data);

  $curl= curl_init($service_url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dasd:asdas");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
  );
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  echo $result;
```

Comment: Your curl configuration does not make any sense. GET request with POST data?

Comment: Can you try it with `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); ` and tell if it makes any difference?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try to follow this code:

```
    $service_url = $myURL;
    $data = array("period" => array("startdate"=>"2018-07-06+00:00:00","enddate"=>"2018-07-07+00:00:00"));                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    $curl= curl_init($service_url);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "fsd:fsdfsdfsdfdf");                                                                    
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );                                                                                                                   
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                                                                                                           
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Get this {"errors":["Method Not Allowed. Use (?-mix:^GET$)"]}

Comment: If I change  from POS to GET it works! 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize curl

```
$ch = curl_init('http://test/statistics.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Basic HTTP authentication:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'fsd:fsdfsdfsdfdf');
```

Custom headers:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
]);
```

JSON payload:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode([
    'period' => [
        'startdate' => '2018-07-06+00:00:00',
        'enddate' => '2018-06-03+00:00',
    ],
]));
```

Execute the request:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if (!empty($error)) {
    die(sprintf('Response error: %s', $error));
}

$jsonResponse = json_decode($response, true);

if (json_last_error()) {
    die(sprintf('Malformed JSON received: %s', json_last_error_msg()));
}

print_r($jsonResponse);
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` for a GET request?

Comment: This will result in a `POST` request. `GET` is not meant for sending any data unless using query parameters in the URL. If you have control over the given endpoint, the data will be accessible in the request body (not the `_POST` superglobal).

Comment: If this results in a `POST` request it might be useless since "_...only GET is accepted._"

Comment: So the endpoint expects data to be sent but prevents it? lol Anyway you can try [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) where you have much more control over the request.

Comment: Get this message from service, {"errors":["Method Not Allowed. Use (?-mix:^GET$)"]}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data within the body over HTTP, you cannot use the `GET` HTTP-Method. To send data within the body you can use other HTTP-Methods like `POST`.

The reason why it's work if you exlude the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option is, that 
**cURL**  sets the `CURLOPT_POST` to `1` automatically if you set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. So your GET request becomes a POST request. That's the reason why get **The server only accepts GET** as a response.

See here: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html

> Using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS implies setting CURLOPT_POST to 1.

There the server, you use, only accept GET (that's how you said) you **cannot** send JSON Data in the body.

But if you want to send data over GET and not over POST, use HTTP query parameters.
Here are some informations on [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

Comment: Have tried query parameters. And that does not work either.

But this works.
curl -i -X GET -u user:userpass --url http://test/statistics.json \
-d '{"period":{"startdate":"YYYY-MM-DD+hh:mm:ss","enddate":"YYYY-MM-DD+hh:mm:ss"}}' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-type: application/json'

Answer (score 0):

This works fine! Thanks **Ray A**!

```
$service_url = "https://test/urk.json";
$data = array("period" => array("startdate"=>"2018-06-01+00:00:00","enddate"=>"2018-07-07+00:00:00"));
$data_string = json_encode($data);

  $curl= curl_init($service_url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dasd:asdas");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
  );
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  echo $result;
```